# How to integrate a simple API in an Android application

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I need to integrate a simple Web API in my Android application, and I was looking for a way to do that.

I was told I should use a service, but other peoples told be about Robospice, AsyncTasks, and Java Threads.

What should I use ? Is there some ressources out there ?

Comment: That's a very broad question, with no single right answer. I suggest the [Building Apps With Network Operations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html) lesson from the Android tutorial as a place to start. RoboSpice and the like build on top of these concepts, but you need to get some sense of the basics first. There are better lessons around if you search for a bit, but I don't have anything bookmarked.

Comment: I'm trying to use an XML API. It is supposed to authentication (so everytime you start the application or try to do an operation the login context should be checked, and you should be redirected on a login activity), file upload, and collecting some informations. I understand this is a broad question, but I'm rather wondering what I should use, because everytime I ask someone for this he would give me another solution and that isn't helping me.

Comment: @servabat, What you're trying to do is not trivial at all. You need to have a fundamental understanding of the platform. You can't just wire up one or two tutorials you find on the internet. Also, don't expect us to do all that research and all the explaining for you. First decompose the problem into smaller parts, and research each part independently. If you still haven't given up by then, then try to get one thing working at a time.  This may take you between six months and 4 weeks, depending on your current level of Java and your level of motivation.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: I'm not trying to find a fast and easy solution, but because it is time consuming as you explain, I'm trying to find the solution I should 'learn', in order not to waste time on a bad solution.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in Android, there can be multiple perfectly valid answer to the same question. Just don't expect each answer to be all encompassing. Once decomposed, your problem is asking for many different things. It would take an entire book to answer everything adequately. And to be honest, those books already exist. So if you haven't taken the time to read/peruse the various books available on Android programming on Amazon or in a bookstore, it's very likely that you won't even take the time to properly read the answer of someone who gives you a very thoughtful fifty pages answer.

Comment: Also, there is no shortcut. You need to learn the difference between different fundamental concepts, even if you do not use all the concepts in one go. Here take this Android course. It's free (if you don't need a certificate) and it starts today. https://www.coursera.org/course/androidpart1 (I know threads are only discussed during part 2, but I implore you not to skip the first four weeks of part 1)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: Thanks, I will look at this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84018/discussion-between-servabat-and-stephan-branczyk).

Answer (score 1):

This goes through integrating a Web API into an Android app step by step, using AsyncTask.

http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes

Answer (score 0):

For more improved and fast response use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) with [Gson](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson17jar.htm) library : You will find a complete tutorial [here](http://www.ottodroid.net/?p=246)